# Is it correct to say that xvalues have identity and are movable?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

According to this document:

http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf

1. l-values have identity and are not movable.
2. pr-values are movable but don't have identity.
3. x-values have identity and are movable.

I have a couple of questions around these.

a. What's the example of an x-value having identity? The following isn't legal:

```
Foo f;
&std::move(f);
```

b. I could overload the &-operator of class Foo and make it return **this** so that the following becomes legal:

```
&Foo(5);
```

But pr-values like Foo(5) cannot have identity. Or is there a subtler interpretation of identity?

Comment: An xvalue typically is the result of casting to an rvalue reference, or accessing a member of an xvalue class object. So, for example, `auto x = 42; static_cast<int&&>(x)` the result of this `static_cast` is an xvalue.

Comment: Have you read the formal specifications of value categories in the Standard? I'm also a bit confused about this "has identity" principle (that is also used as the definition of "object" by some people), but the Standard does not seem to make use of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is there a subtler interpretation of identity?

The document you linked contains these two definitions:

> - “has identity” – i.e. and address, a pointer, the user can determine whether two copies are
>   identical, etc.
> - “can be moved from” – i.e. we are allowed to leave to source of a “copy” in some indeterminate,
>   but valid state

Taking a look at the Standard we can gather the definition of an *object* (as per §1.8/1) is:

> An object is a region of storage.

that as per, §1.7/1:

> Every byte has a unique address.

has an *address*. This means that the definition is awfully broad and includes pretty much every object of any type of value (rvalue, xvalue, prvalue, lvalue, etc..).

---

> What's the example of an x-value having identity?

The standard itself gives a list of expressions that generates xvalues (at §5/7):

> An expression is an xvalue if it is:
>
> - the result of calling a function, whether implicitly or explicitly, whose return type is an rvalue reference
>   to object type,
> - a cast to an rvalue reference to object type,
> - a class member access expression designating a non-static data member of non-reference type in which the object expression is an xvalue, or
> - a .* pointer-to-member expression in which the first operand is an xvalue and the second operand is a pointer to data member.
>
> In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are treated as xvalues; rvalue references to functions are treated as lvalues whether namedornot.

And as a follow up few examples are given. Here's an extension to them:

```
struct A { int m; };

A&& operator+(A, A);
A a;
A b;
a + b;   // xvalue

A&& f();
f();     // xvalue
f().m;   // xvalue

A a;
static_cast<A&&>(a);  // xvalue
std::move(a);         // xvalue
```

Comment: What's the identity of an x-value expression? How do you get it? What's the identity (or address) of the expression std::move(a)? I would imagine it is &a. But we cannot apply the &-operator to it. How is that different from a pr-value? Or is it the fact that a name is bound to the underlying object but the x-value expression makes it possible to move from.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee: It is an interesting question.  I'm not sure of the rationale behind not allowing the address of an xvalue, but I suspect it is just to avoid mistakes.  xvalues are fairly rare in practice, so there isn't much of a reason to make getting their address very convenient.  An xvalue will convert to a const lvalue reference though, and then you can get the address of the referenced object.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee: It still raises the question about what "identity" is though, since you can bind a const reference to a prvalue as well.   It seems like the difference comes down to whether a temporary is involved.  So does a temporary become non-temporary once a reference is bound to it and its address can be taken?  I suppose that is one way of looking at it.

Answer (score 6):

The following from Stroutrup's The C++ Programming Language might clear this question up:

```
void f(vector<string>& vs)
{
vector<string>& v2 = std::move(vs);// move vs to v2
// ...
}

Here, std::move(vs) is an xvalue: it
clearly has identity (we can refer to
it as vs), but we have explicitly given
permission for it to be moved from by
calling std::move() (§3.3.2, §35.5.1).
For practical programming, thinking in
terms of rvalue and lvalue is usually 
sufficient.
```